# Elastic Search "must_not" doesn't work with strings at "filter"

Tags: elasticsearch

Why must_not doesn't work at "filter"? (look at the picture below).

Same "must_not" works at "query" (commented on the picture)

[image]

Query as a text:

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": { 
     "query": {
      "bool": {
       "must": [
        {"match": {"ObjectData.PRTNAME":{"query": "1","fuzziness": "auto"}}},
        {"match": {"mostRecentVersion": true}}
       ]
     //  ,  "must_not": { "match": { "ObjectData.STATE": "ACTIVE"  }}
      }
     },
     "filter": {
       "bool": {
         "must":  [
            {"term": {"ObjectData.ISCLIENT": "1"}},
            {"term": {"mostRecentVersion": "true"}}
         ],
         "must_not": [
            { "term": {"ObjectData.PARTICIPANTTYPE": 4}},
            { "term": {"ObjectData.ISTAXRESIDENT": 0}},
            { "term": {"ObjectData.STATE": "ACTIVE"}}
         ]
       }
     }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's probably because your `ObjectData.STATE` is an analyzed string. Try `{ "term": {"ObjectData.STATE": "active"}}` and it should work.

Comment: Yes. It's work. Thank you again, Val! But when we add document to ES we put ObjectData.STATE as "ACTIVE". Why ES changes it to "active"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably because your `ObjectData.STATE` is an analyzed string. Try this instead and it should work.

```
{ "term": {"ObjectData.STATE": "active"}}
```

If you want to keep querying with `ACTIVE` instead of `active` then you need to change the mapping of `ObjectData.STATE` from

```
{
    "STATE": {
       "type": "string"
    }
}
```

To

```
{
    "STATE": {
       "type": "string",
       "index": "not_analyzed"
    }
}
```

Or if you're using ES 5 to

```
{
    "STATE": {
       "type": "keyword"
    }
}
```